# Find the root of a yarn mono-repo programmatically

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I am writing a cli tool, and I want to detect the root of a mono-repo no matter what is the `cwd`. What is the best way to do achieve it?
If it helps, I am targeting yarn3.
Is there a way to somehow utilize `@yarnpkg/core` for this task?